# Issue to build project with gradle 8.5 and java 21

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I use java 21
gradle 8.5
intellij 2023.2.2

In a spring boot 3.2 project in the build.gradle i have

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.acme.intranet-backend'
version '0.0.34-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '21'
}
```

when i build project,  i

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
> ':intranet:compileJava'.  at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
> at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
> at  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error: invalid
> source release: 21

Comment: It seems it using an older Java version to build.

Comment: Can you check your `JAVA_HOME` as well as the output of `javac -version`?

Comment: I wonder if your are actually using Gradle 8.5. I imagine an earlier version of Gradle might throw that error.

Comment: You can see both the Java and Gradle version actually in use by running `./gradlew --version` (assuming you use the wrapper).

Answer (score 3):

By default, IDEA uses Gradle wrapper which in turn uses its own configuration of Java runtime.

If you go into

```
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle
```

you can change Gradle default JVM into Java 21 ("Gradle JVM" property).

If you do not have JDK 21 installed, select "Download SDK" and pick one of Java 21 versions (personally I prefer Eclipse Temurin SDK).